# OpenCL and Radeon 550 with opensource driver

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, opencl

As from title, I would like to know how to use the **OpenCL** features with an **AMD Radeon RX 550** graphic card through the opensource driver on the latest versions of Ubuntu. I tried with the opensource **AmdGPU** driver (the default one with Ubuntu), but there was no way. The result is always the same with Ubuntu 17.04 and Ubuntu 17.10:

```
~ $ clinfo

Number of platforms                0
```

The only way I was able to use **OpenCL** with that card was to install Ubuntu 16.04 with **AmdGPU Pro** proprietary drivers. Any ideas?

Comment: Please share how you were able to get it working with the proprietary drivers, as they aren't working for me with my RX550 / Ubuntu 16.04. What kernel(s) have you tried? I'm currently on `4.10.0-28-lowlatency`

Comment: https://boinc.berkeley.edu/dev/forum_thread.php?id=11417 -- this link suggests it is possible to use the opensource driver while "borrowing" libraries from the amdgpu-pro drivers.  i don't have radeon hardware to confirm.